# Outlook alert within my winform

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

Hi guys i am new to all of this and completely self taught so i may confuse you as i do myself but here it goes.
i have made a KB app at work using Win Forms c# for use with level one support. in this app i would like it to give out a sound alert and alert box when a email is received into a certain mailbox in outlook. in the simplest way possible would be amazing. any help on where to start is appreciated. i have looked around for some answers but they seemed to not be quite what i am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Your question contains way to much unnecessary information and almost no details on the actual subject itself. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and rewrite your question.

Comment: so what have i missed? its a simple winform app. within it i want to catch and create a alert from a outlook inbox. literally does what it says on the tin... i am asking this question as i do not have any more info or details and need a reference on where to start. :)

Comment: First, remove all the "Hi guys", "would be amazing", "Thanks", etc. While that may be common on other sites, on StackOverflow you stick to the facts. Secondly, as it is now you are asking for multiple things at once and we have no way of knowing which one is giving you trouble: Is your app connected to the mailserver directly or do you communicate with an outlook plugin? Don't you know how to *"give out sound alert"*, and if you do know, why include it in the question? What have you tried so far and why didn't it work? (SO is not a code-writing service).

Comment: manners mate. sorted now.

Answer (score 2):

```html
     Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace;
     Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox;
     Outlook.Items items;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
                    OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

            items = inbox.Items;
            items.ItemAdd +=
                new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
        }

        void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
        {
            string filter = "USED CARS";
            Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
            if (Item != null)
            {
                if (mail.MessageClass == "IPM.Note" &&
                           mail.Subject.ToUpper().Contains(filter.ToUpper()))
                {
                    mail.Move(outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
                        OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJunk));
                }
            }

        }
```

Try this solution from the Microsoft site it gets triggerd when a mail is recieved.

See docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268998.aspx

Comment: Thanks buddy, found this the other day and couldn't dig it back up.